# Choose an ID and give me all buyers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an `carid` and I would like to see all buyers who had something to do with this `carid`. So I would like to have all buyers who have bought `carid` 3.
How do I do that?

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Buyerid': [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5],
     'Carid': [1,2,3,4,4,1,2,4,1,3,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

    Buyerid  Carid
0         1      1
1         1      2
2         2      3
3         2      4
4         3      4
5         3      1
6         3      2
7         4      4
8         5      1
9         5      3
10        5      5

# What I want

    Buyerid  Carid
2         2      3
3         2      4
8         5      1
9         5      3
10        5      5
```

I have already tested this `df = df.loc[df['Carid']==3,'Buyerid']`, but this only gives me the line with `CardID` 3 but not the complete buyer.
[How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

I looked at that, but I only get this here

```
   Buyerid  Carid
2         2      3
9         5      3
```

Comment: Is `carid` the `itemid`?

Comment: Yes you're right. thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with the Pandas user guide practicing the examples. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html, [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html#boolean-indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: @wwii I'm not sure to what extent that is a good duplicate

Comment: @wwii Well, 
I've already tried something, but I always only get one line and not the entire buyer ....

Comment: @DaniMesejo you are right..this is not dupe..reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Buyerid': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5],
     'Carid': [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# get all buyers
buyers = set(df.loc[df['Carid'] == 3, 'Buyerid'])

# boolean mask for filtering
mask = df['Buyerid'].isin(buyers)

print(df[mask])
```

**Output**

```
    Buyerid  Carid
2         2      3
3         2      4
8         5      1
9         5      3
10        5      5
```

Comment: Yes, only I was only able to vote in 3 minutes, that's why I couldn't accept it directly

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Carid']==3,'Buyerid']
```

Comment: Thank you, but that only gives me the one line with the carid I would like to have the complete buyer with it